# How can I calculate the level of agreement between my K-Means cluster labels and my ground truth labels in R?

Tags: clustering, image-classification, k-means, accuracy, variance

I have made a K-Means clustering from 3 rasters with various values of k (k=2, k=4, k=7) and would like to know which values of k explains the most variance in my ground-truth data or the value of k that has the highest level of agreement with my ground-truth data. My ground-truth data is made up of actual species counts per station. So I extracted the values to points in the K-Means classification for each ground station like below:

```
k=2:                 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1
K=4:                 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1
K=7:                 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 3, 7, 3, 5, 2, 2
Ground-truth labels: 3, 1, 2, 13, 26, 0, 3, 1, 11, 0, 0, 2, 9, 1
```

Kindly help